# How do you install or upgrade to a release candidate of TortoiseSVN?

Tags: installation, tortoisesvn, upgrade, nightly-build

I've never had cause to use a nightly build or a release candidate of TortoiseSVN before but when trying to create a patch, I got the following crash dump page: https://drdump.com/UploadedReport.aspx?ProblemID=175094&DumpID=8037510

I'd like to try out the fix that is mentioned but I really don't know what to do with the DLLs and ZIP files located at https://nightlybuilds.tortoisesvn.net/1.9.x/x64/full/

Comment: The [link](https://nightlybuilds.tortoisesvn.net/) has the information needed.

Comment: @SureshKoya Thank you! I was not aware of the instructions located there.  The instructions mention running an MSI file.  Is this the "TortoiseSVN 1.9.3 - 64-bit" link referenced on https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html or is there supposed to be an MSI file located somewhere in https://nightlybuilds.tortoisesvn.net/latest/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the instruction in the [web site](https://nightlybuilds.tortoisesvn.net/)

> The 'Latest/' folder contains files which are built daily from the HEAD
>   revision of TSVN trunk code, which is useful for testing the latest changes.
>   These are not official released files, so any new features may not have
>   been extensively tested.

You can take the files from the Latest build and replace the files in your local directory. Make sure to make a copy of the files you have locally in a separate directory so that you can fallback.

I believe the last build succeeded but upload of the Installer have failed. You might want to followup in their [mailing list](https://tortoisesvn.net/community.html).

```
 [exec] Uploading...
 [exec] ERROR: SOAP 1.2 fault: SOAP-ENV:Sender[no subcode]
 [exec] "HttpSendRequest failed"
 [exec] Detail: The operation timed out
```

Comment: do I need to unzip any of the ZIP files? Or just leave them as is?

Answer (score 0):

The nightly builds failed for several reasons ([symbol server was down because of network and HDD issues](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=3168945) and [certificate had to be renewed](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=3169434))

Now you an download the nightlies again.

Get here the nightly for the [trunk builds](https://nightlybuilds.tortoisesvn.net/latest/) and [1.9 builds](https://nightlybuilds.tortoisesvn.net/1.9.x/). Install the MSI just like you do with normal releases.

Comment: thank you! I was able to download and install the MSI